# how to add button in the last cell of table?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using tableView .

Now I want to make a button in my last cell??

can anyone tell me how to do this??

other data I am getting by an array . I want to add the button after the last element of the table

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any specific reason to display the button when user scroll till end of the last row of the table,

> if yes:
>
> then you can add your button in **tableFooterView**
>
> else :
>
> you can reduce the height of your table view in such a way so you can
>   add a custom view contains your button and place your custom view
>   after your tableView

Answer (score 0):

Add your button as a `tableFooterView` of the table, this is much simpler than trying to use a custom cell for the last row.

Answer (score 0):

i am not having my mac right now trying to guide you: 
1.Implement CellForRowAtIndexPath method.
2.u can use something like
 `if (indexpath.row==[array count])
{
//make button here with cgrectmake and add to the view

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect/custom/...];

[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)

forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[cell addSubview:button ];

}` 
 hope it help you